# unhappy with MySQL workbench 5.2

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is there a better option for windows out there?
I come froma MS SQL-Server environment so something that's similar to their editor would probably be most preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What capabilities are you looking for. 
MySQL Workbench evolves really quick and the 5.3 should be out fairly soon.

I don't think there's anything comparatively good unless you simply use phpmyadmin...

The 5.3 should be out soon with its load of fixed bugs.

What don't you like with it. Maybe I can help if I understand.

Comment: I guess the easiest thing to add that i feel is missing is paren matching/highlighting.

Comment: also, i find the 'ctrl+z' functionality a little kitschy. It undoes the last implied move instead of the last actual move. So, say I delete a bunch of text with a new line (in one action). first, ctrl+z would return the newline and then it would return the text as though i did two separate actions. It's the little things that annoy me most....

Comment: Yes indeed. I'm not sure I can do anything about that x)

It's always useful to notify the errors.They are debugged as they are noticed.

Comment: also, it would be *REALLY* awesome if I could turn off the "sort column by clicking on it" option. I find that to normally be a mistake that costs me a couple minutes every time I mistakenly hit it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a better option for you if you have to work with MySQL.

I agree with you: MySQL Workbench generally could behave much better; some operations simply produce no output leaving you wondering what happened. If you're used to Microsoft SQL Server, you'll likely miss the capability to run several queries in one code editor window, producing several outputs at the same time. This is the biggest usability drawback, in my opinion.

There are some things MySQL does better though, so it's a mixed bag.